# How to display questions one by one on save and next basis

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a quiz management system and need to fetch the data from the database and displaying the data one by one on clicking next button.

I want to use Ajax to insert data into database after clicking next button by using file read and write function.

---

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl_question where setid='$set' and status=1 ORDER BY RAND()");
while($sha=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 

<h4><? echo $sha['id'];?></h4>
```

---

I want to submit questions by Ajax. Please suggest me solution.

Comment: Start by searching for "Getting started with Ajax" and make some attempts. If you then run into some _specific_ issue, come back, show us what you've tried and we can take it from there. Currently, this question is too broad. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Learn about SQL Injection. **please** always, always, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this [response](https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2) to create three questions which appear on clicking the button.

I hope answer is self explanatory. If not please let me know. I have used vanilla js. Cheers.

```js
window.onload = getRequest();

let response;
let allFirstNames;
let questionDiv = document.getElementById("question");

function getRequest() {
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        response = xmlhttp.responseText;
        parseResponse()
     }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function parseResponse() {
   allFirstNames = JSON.parse(response)["data"].map((dataObj) => {
     return dataObj["first_name"];
   });
}

document.getElementById("printQ").onclick = printQuestions;

function printQuestions() {
   clearCurrentQuestions();
     if (allFirstNames[0] != undefined) {
       let question = document.createElement("p");
       question.innerHTML = "Who is "+ allFirstNames[0] + " ?";
       document.getElementById("question").appendChild(question);
       allFirstNames.splice(0,1);
      }
      else {
         let question = document.createElement("p");
         question.innerHTML = "No More Questions. End of Quiz";
         document.getElementById("question").appendChild(question);
      }
}

function clearCurrentQuestions() {
   let node = document.getElementById("question")
   while(node.hasChildNodes()) {
     node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
   }
}
```

```html
<button id="printQ">
Print Next Question
</button>
<div id="question">
<p>
Hi, Welcome to the Quiz, Click above button for Qns
</p>
</div>
```